No OS found uefi problems
I was running ubuntu for a few years.  I tried to get secure boot to work.  I was playing with UEFI; and then no matter what I set things to, I couldn't boot.  For now I am starting it with a live disk.  I was booting with UEFI/linux/grubx64 I changed it and tried adding the keys to the OS.  I got a message about no OS to boot; I reset everything I could think of; but it won't boot off of the NVMe, only the external HD.  I went into grub on the USB drive; but I don't even see the NVMe drive.  I ran boot repair; it changed my UEFI boot settings; but I still get no os found.  What can I do next?  I don't think reinstalling the OS will help; and recovering from backups sounds like a royal pain.
Edit 1:
I turned off secure boot; set first option to grubx.  I can do grubx on the USB drive; but not on the NVMe
It's a dell OptiPlex 5060  I tried adding the NVMe drive to the boot options on the USB drive; but it doesn't find it automatically.
The drive name is /dev/nvme0n1p2; grub should be there.  The drive I can boot from is /dev/sda3.  Since UEFI says there is no OS on the NVMe; Is there a way to write it to that drive?  Is there a group of files I should look for on /dev/nvme0n1p2 to verify why it won't boot?

What Brand/Model system? Several brands like HP or Acer require you to change settings in UEFI settings. If turning on UEFI Secure boot you need to reinstall grub in Secure boot mode as then grub uses shimx64.efi and has to have kernels & drivers all signed. User must create signed for proprietary drivers like nVidia with MOK machine owner key.

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details for us to provide specific help with anyway; but most Ubuntu installers (there have been 5 used in the last few years; you don't specify product/releases so we have no idea) only setup the system for Secure Boot if its detected as enabled at install; if it's disabled at install time it isn't usually setup. You've not told us what you installed, how installed or specifics on what was changed.  FYI:  Some products allow a non-destructive re-install also; so re-install may not require you to touch backups.

the nvme has Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.  the usb drive has Ubuntu 24.10

Well; I had a small partition 1 on my SSD: I reformatted that; put grub on that; now it boots off of partition 1 and loads partition 2.  This works!  Not sure what went wrong.  Installing grub was tedious; I needed to reformat the partition; and only install grub not the full OS.

are you able to get into the "BIOS setup" by pressing f10 (or similar) when the computer first starts up? if so, then TURN OFF SECURE BOOT. i have played around with secure boot in the past, and got it working, but to be honest it is a right pain. once you have your machine booting as you want it is far easier to instead just turn off 'boot from USB' options in the "BIOS setup".
